# Gnome slowed down

Tags: gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I didn't install any extension for gnome. I'm experiencing a slow down on gnome atm. I think it is related to gnome because animations and responds to clicking anywhere are too late. Also, when I check through the system monitor I don't see anything sucking up cpu or memory resources. I didn't restart the pc because I'm trying to understand what's wrong but I can't find the source of the problem. Please help.

```
top - 20:24:13 up  9:07,  1 user,  load average: 1,71, 2,33, 2,07
Tasks: 228 total,   1 running, 227 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 16,0 us,  3,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 80,7 id,  0,2 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,1 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   7875,4 total,   1451,5 free,   2975,8 used,   3448,1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.   3884,6 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
   8229 bwd       20   0 2871280 582308  90384 S  22,2   7,2  92:25.05 vlc      
   3466 bwd       20   0 3089520 437696 158256 S  12,3   5,4  37:43.07 Web Con+ 
   1751 bwd       20   0 4648148 300612 103476 S   9,6   3,7  31:48.10 gnome-s+ 
   2165 bwd       20   0 5304736 893148 271752 S   7,9  11,1 124:43.32 firefox  
   1599 bwd       20   0  877768  82296  50772 S   7,6   1,0  19:19.15 Xorg     
   3891 bwd       20   0 2904648 276308 128720 S   5,3   3,4  51:26.22 Web Con+ 
  17806 bwd       20   0 3114048 346728 201176 S   4,0   4,3   7:40.82 Web Con+ 
   1518 bwd        9 -11 3320784  27132  22608 S   3,0   0,3  12:20.77 pulseau+ 
  18969 bwd       20   0  965240  51764  39000 S   2,3   0,6   0:02.30 gnome-t+ 
  17627 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   1,3   0,0   0:26.96 kworker+ 
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:36.60 rcu_sch+ 
    823 root      20   0    2548    780    708 S   0,3   0,0   0:36.39 acpid    
    856 root      20   0   16764   8172   7112 S   0,3   0,1   0:09.36 systemd+ 
   1796 bwd       20   0  162836   7700   6928 S   0,3   0,1   0:06.56 at-spi2+ 
   2653 bwd       20   0 3895832 515788 228472 S   0,3   6,4  44:23.20 Web Con+ 
   2696 bwd       20   0 2850952 216420  94508 S   0,3   2,7  17:01.47 WebExte+ 
  15762 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:00.87 kworker+ 
  15774 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:07.98 kworker+ 
  17551 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:03.00 kworker+ 
  17844 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   0:03.71 kworker+ 
  18750 bwd       20   0 2665996 201636 137820 S   0,3   2,5   0:10.74 Web Con+ 
      1 root      20   0  167644  11472   8264 S   0,0   0,1   0:02.60 systemd  
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 kthreadd 
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_gp   
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 rcu_par+ 
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kworker+ 
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 mm_perc+ 
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:01.34 ksoftir+ 
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.12 migrati+ 

total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,7Gi       2,9Gi       1,4Gi       723Mi       3,4Gi       3,8Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

**vm.swappiness = 60**

Comment: You're probably seeing the notorious gnome-shell memory leak. Edit your question and show me `top` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: I don't have the problem atm. Would it still help if I add this info now?

Comment: Yes. Run the system for a while, then get the data that I need.

Comment: So far, the only thing that managed to cause UI lag on my gnome-shell 3.36 on Ubuntu 20.04 was the Nemo file manager (of Cinnamon DE origin).